# Oracle Apex application and database

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, exadata

Can I run Oracle Apex application on window's server and connected database to linux server?

More info,
I want to run my oracle apex application on windows platform, and i want to have conected database on exadata on linux server. Is it possible to have the network connectivity?

If no, please share the documentation.

Searched everywhere, and ask oracle DBAs

Comment: APEX itself is PL/SQL packages installed *in the database* and is therefore OS-independent.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle APEX runs in the database, but you usually connect to it through Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) that can run standalone where you have Java, or deployed in Tomcat, including Windows. You will access and develop the APEX application with a browser on Windows, or any other place where you have a browser.

Have a look at chapter three in the [installation manual for APEX](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/htmig/index.html)

Comment: Tomcat would be recommended for the ORDS application server. The ORDS stand-alone mode is really only for basic development and not for production use.

Comment: I disagree with you on that one; stand-alone has been running stable for a long time. What problems have you been facing?

Comment: It's not about "problems". That recommendation is right out of Oracle's documentation. It's not intended for production use.

Comment: From the latest installation manual, 6.1.1: "Standalone mode is suitable for development use and is supported in production deployments. Standalone mode, however, has minimal management capabilities when compared to most Java EE application servers and may not have adequate management capabilities for production use in some environments."

If you don't need this management capabilities, standalone is just fine and supported.